# Django-mptt model does not order by profile (ForeignKey), but it does after rebuild()

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-mptt

Django-mptt model does not order by (`order_insertion_by`) profile (ForeignKey), but it does after rebuild()

models.py

```py
class Product(MPTTModel):
    # fields
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    # more fields
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['profile']
```

Profile is also an MPTT model connected to User by OneToOneField

models.py

```py
class Profile(MPTTModel):
    # fields
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # more fields

    class Meta:
        abstrat = False
        ordering = ["user__last_name", "user__first_name", "user__username"]

    class MPTTMeta:
        parent_attr = "manager"

    def get_name(self):
        return f"{self.user.last_name}, {self.user.first_name}"
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_name()
```

If I save some data, then `order_insertion_by` will order the data by id and not by `last_name`,`first_name`. But if I save and `rebuild()` the Product objects `Product.objects.rebuild()`, then it orders by `last_name`,`first_name`.

The structure is:

- Product (root)

  - Product (child) *(needs to be sorted by profile and is the only child which contains profile)*

    - Product (child of child)

      - Product (child of child of child)

I want to understand why I need to use `rebuild()`, as `rebuild()` takes a lot of resources.